# Different font when hovering over menu point (Elementor Pro)

Tags: css, menu, elementor

when using the default "Nav Menu" widget in Elementor Pro, I'm facing the lack of features that don't allow to modify the font styling of the currently active site in the menu.
I need to create the following menu:

[image]

the page called "vita" represents the active page.

Do you have any idea for a workaround?